# How save custome data and add new cart item instead of update quantity when product add to cart in magneto

Tags: php, magento

I want to save custom data in to cart item and add new cart item instead of update quantity when product add to cart in magneto.

I have added below code in **Observer.php** file

```
public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        $product = $observer->getProduct();      
        try {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $data = $this->_getRequest()->getPost();
            $customize_price = $data['customize_price'];
            $customize_data = $data['customize_data'];
            $customize_status = $data['customize_status'];
            $customize_description = $data['customize_description'];
            $checkProduct = Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/productsetting')->loadByProductId($productId);
            if($checkProduct->getProductId() == ''){                
                $productModel = Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/productsetting');
                $productModel->setProductId($productId);
                $productModel->setCustomizePrice($customize_price);
                $productModel->setCustomizeData($customize_data);
                $productModel->setCustomizeStatus($customize_status);
                $productModel->setCustomizeDescription($customize_description);
                $productModel->save();
            } else {
                $checkProduct = Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/productsetting')->loadByProductId($productId);
                $checkProduct->setCustomizePrice($customize_price);
                $checkProduct->setCustomizeData($customize_data);
                $checkProduct->setCustomizeStatus($customize_status);
                $checkProduct->setCustomizeDescription($customize_description);
                $checkProduct->save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

It is saving custom data into cart item but when i add same product in to cart then it is updating quantity. I want to add new item instead of update quantity.

I want to add separately because "customization data" and "price" of the product is different every time when add item into cart.